# How to implement insertion sort to my ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, insertion-sort

I have this Homework problem that I've been able to do fairly easily, but I'm stuck on how to implement insertion sort to an ArrayList I've constructed.

Here's my code so far:

```
public class EmailDirectory 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new EmailDirectory();               //relay main menu until 3 is entered
}

public ArrayList<String> emailRecords=new ArrayList<String>();  //construct Array for directory, Array or ArrayList?

public EmailDirectory()
{
    Scanner scnr=new Scanner(System.in);    //scanner and empty string for option choice
    String menuChoice;

    do{     //do while to keep repeating
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of your option choice:");
        System.out.println("1. Add a new contact");
        System.out.println("2. Search for an exsisting contact");
        System.out.println("3. Exit");
        menuChoice=scnr.nextLine(); 

            if (menuChoice.equals("1"))     //add new contact   
            {
                addContact();
            }   

            else if (menuChoice.equals("2"))    //search contacts
            {
                searchContact();
            }
      }
    while(menuChoice.equals("3")==false);
}

private void addContact()   
{
    Scanner addCont=new Scanner(System.in);     //scanner for new contact
    String newCont;

    System.out.println("Please enter the email adress.");   //prompt for user
    newCont=addCont.nextLine();
    emailRecords.add(newCont);                  //add to array for access later
    insertionSort(emailRecords);

}

private void searchContact()    
{
    //TODO
    System.out.println(emailRecords);           //test output, change laster
}

public void insertionSort(ArrayList<String> emailrecords)   //insertion sort, pass by parameter?
{    
    int i,j;
    String key;
    ArrayList<String> inputArray=emailRecords;

    for (j=1; j<inputArray.size(); j++) 
        {
            key = inputArray.get(j);
            i = j - 1;
                while (i >= 0)
                {
                    if (key.compareTo(inputArray.get(i)) > 0) {
                    break;
                }
             String element=inputArray.get(i+1);
             element = inputArray.get(i);
             i--;
         }
         String element=inputArray.get(i+1);
         element = key;
    }
    }
}
```

The homework problem is to create an email directory and keep it sorted using insertion, but i cant seem to figure out why the array wont sort.  Im able to add emails, but when i print it out is just appends it to the end.

suggestions and advise will be greatly appreciated, thanks so much!

Comment: Time to debug your program. Try stepping through this with a debugger, or at least add some print statements, to figure out when the program's execution differs from your expectations. Try to narrow it down to a single line.

Comment: Hint: the name 'insertion sort' implies that somewhere during the algorithm something is *inserted*

Comment: i did't see something like **inputArray.set(...)**.

Comment: It may be easier to declare a new `List` and remove the objects one by one from the old list and insert it into the new `List` in order.

Comment: If you aren't tied to ArrayList, you may find that a doubly linked list (LinkedList probably) is the better option here. That way you aren't needing to move things around in the array (something you need to be but aren't actually doing at this point).

Comment: Hint 2:  In case your response to copeg is, "I do!  `emailRecords.add(newCont)`."  You never swap any of the values around in the list.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, it was much appreciated!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

fix the sort function like this:

```
 public void insertionSort(ArrayList<String> emailrecords)   //insertion sort, pass by parameter?
    {    
    int i,j;
    String key;
    ArrayList<String> inputArray=emailRecords;

    for (j=1; j<inputArray.size(); j++) 
        {
            key = inputArray.get(j);
            i = j - 1;
                while (i >= 0)
                {
                    if (key.compareTo(inputArray.get(i)) > 0) {
                    break;
                }
             String element=inputArray.get(i+1);             //here
             inputArray.set(i+1,inputArray.get(i));          //here
             inputArray.set(i,element);                      //here
             i--;
         }
         key=inputArray.get(i+1);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dang, i should have seen that a mile away...thank man, that really helped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is with the actual sort.

In the insertionSort() method you are passing in an ArrayList emailrecords to be sorted.  You are then setting it equal to another ArrayList inputArray and then sorting that one.

Try just sorting the original ArrayList emailrecords and see if that works.

This is a great demo of all the sorts. [http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/ComparisonSort.html]
 Click Insertion Sort on top.